# Encrypt with K1, K2 and decrypt in opposite with K2, K1

Tags: encryption, symmetric, keys

When using symmetric cipher, does the following statement holds:

`E(x, k)` means encrypting x with key k in ECB mode

`E(E(x, k1), k2) = E(E(x, k2), k1)` ?

Then the decryption could go in opposite way round and the message x would be the same.

Comment: I think the term you are looking for is [tag:commutative-encryption]. Modern block ciphers are not commutative, so the statement does not hold for them in ECB mode.

Comment: Your title is backwards: you want to decrypt in the *same* order as you encrypted. If you decrypt in the opposite order, it always works.

Comment: @SEJPM With CTR, it depends a bit on how you deal with the IV. If the second encryption also encrypts the IV from the first encryption, then the output is different.

Comment: @cpast, thank you. **corrected TL;DR:** Won't work with ECB (as asked in your question). Will work with CTR, if you don't encrypt the IV.